# Getting values of checkboxes along with uploading the file

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I was trying to upload an image in java using commonsIO  and Jar for file upload.But the problem am facing is that i am having two checkboxes on my form as follow :

```
<div style="float:left">
  <input name="Mcheckbox" type="checkbox" value="Mobile"/>
  Mobile
</div>
<div style="float:right">
  <input name="Echechkbox" type="checkbox" value="Email"/>
  Email
</div>
```

And then browse option :

```
Upload Image : <INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="file" value="file"></input>
```

And in my servlet am doing something like this :

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
List<FileItem> files = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
Iterator it = files.iterator();
```

And then:

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    FileItem fi = (FileItem) it.next();

    if (fi.isFormField()) {
        if (fieldname.compareTo("Mcheckbox") == 0) {

            System.out.println("checkbox value is " + fieldvalue);
            mymobilepass = fieldvalue;
        } else if (fieldname.compareTo("Echeckbox") == 0) {

            System.out.println("checkbox value is " + fieldvalue);
            myemailpass = fieldvalue;
        }

    } else {
        InputStream is = fi.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\" + fi.getName());
        int x = is.read();

        while (x >= 0) {
            fos.write((byte) x);
            x = is.read();
            //System.out.println("reading");

        }
    }
}
```

But am getting null as the value of myemailpass or mymobilepass everytime.What can be the reason ? The if statement is never executed .Why ? Please help

Comment: Are you wrapping everything inside `<form>` tag and why dont you get the value as `request.getParameter("Mcheckbox" )`

Comment: @sankrish Yeah am wrapping everything inside form

Comment: @sankrish Because I had parse the request once here :  List<FileItem> files = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);.If i try to get the parameters again then obviously they are going to be NULL .Moreover the form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @LeosLiterak Yeah It is "multipart/form-data"

Comment: @LeosLiterak What you mean by multiple instances?I didnt get you.

Comment: @LeosLiterak I dont think its creating any problem.I checked doing so also.But no help

Comment: Please try it:         DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List<FileItem> files = new ServletFileUpload(factory).parseRequest(request);

Comment: @LeosLiterak I tried it also.No help still

Comment: @user3522121 did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do not set `fieldvalue` in your loop

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> files = new ServletFileUpload(factory).parseRequest(request);

for (FileItem item : files) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
        String fieldvalue = item.getString();
        if (fieldname.compareTo("Mcheckbox") == 0) {
            System.out.println("checkbox value is " + fieldvalue);
            mymobilepass = fieldvalue;
        } else if (fieldname.compareTo("Echeckbox") == 0) {
            System.out.println("checkbox value is " + fieldvalue);
            myemailpass = fieldvalue;
        }

    } else {
        InputStream is = item.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\" + fi.getName());
        int x = is.read();

        while (x >= 0) {
            fos.write((byte) x);
            x = is.read();
            //System.out.println("reading");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way ,

```
 DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload();
        String Chk1= "";
        String Chk2= "";
        try {

            List<FileItem> files= upload.parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item : files) {
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    if (item.getFieldName("Mcheckbox")) {
                       //do some thing here 
                    } 
                }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @sankrish What had you changed ?I didnt see any such change ?

Comment: @user3522121 you didnt use this method `getFieldName()`