# request.getParameter checkbox fileupload

Tags: java, checkbox, file-upload

In a registration form I am using file upload to upload a photo to the database. The problem comes to me with 5 checkboxes that I have in the form, if there is one that does not select the program and I don't know how to solve it.

Previously with a simple request.getParameter I got it but now when using fileupload it is different and I can't get that if I don't select it, I leave it in null.

```
                FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
                ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
                List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request)     
String name=items.get(1).getString();
String date=items.get(2).getString();
String select=items.get(3).getString();
String checkbox1=items.get(4).getName();
```

Comment: Could you explain it more or provide any further information on this?

Comment: i can´t get the checkbox value,I have added more code in the entry of the post

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're using the getName to get the value of checkbox.
If you want to get the name the correct method is getFieldName(). If you only want the value then getString() would suffice.

Try changing the code to

```
String checkbox1=items.get(4).getString();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101319/getting-values-of-checkboxes-along-with-uploading-the-file  

Hae you tried this? First compare the item fieldname (with the name you gave it in the jsp) and then get the value.